# sql server (Two tables and I want to display only one row)

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables ... the first table where the commodity data

The second table in which the images are ... The requested view display the two tables but I want the first picture only for each line of the first table .. I do not want it displays the rest of the pictures.

```
SELECT     dbo.Sell_Items.id_Sell, 
           dbo.Sell_Image.ImageUr
FROM       dbo.Sell_Items 
INNER JOIN dbo.Sell_Image ON dbo.Sell_Items.id_Sell = dbo.Sell_Image.sell_id
```

The first two tables

```
Sell_Items
Sell_Image
```

Comment: `I want the first picture only` ... what defines a picture as being first?  Can you show us some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use an agregation function for get only one result per id_sell

```
    SELECT    dbo.Sell_Items.id_Sell, min(dbo.Sell_Image.ImageUr)
    FROM       dbo.Sell_Items 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Sell_Image ON dbo.Sell_Items.id_Sell= dbo.Sell_Image.sell_id
    group by dbo.Sell_Items.id_Sell
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your `dbo.Sell_Image` you have an unique Id you can try this:

```
 SELECT     dbo.Sell_Items.id_Sell, 
           (SELECT top 1 dbo.Sell_Image.ImageUr
                FROM dbo.Sell_Image
                WHERE dbo.Sell_Items.id_Sell = dbo.Sell_Image.sell_id 
                ORDER BY dbo.Sell_Image.Id) 'ImageUr'

    FROM dbo.Sell_Items
```

and you can get the first or the last based on your ORDER BY command in SubQuery